# Internal REST API versioning strategy

Tags: rest

I have found some strategies for versioning REST APIs via SO and Google etc., but I have not found any strategies for versioning internal REST apis (and I mean by this, that I intend making a web app, an Android app etc that share a common REST api, but the general public will not get access to the API).

Seeing as the API is for internal use only, it would need less backwards compatibility, and basically a way of being 'current' and 'edge' or something similar. Any tips on a nice and simple strategy to version an internal REST api for minimal hassle would be great.

Comment: What is wrong with the versioning that is generally accepted? I don't see how the requirements would change if it were internal or external.  Good practice is good practice.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid sorry, I have never made REST api, so I am ignorant, I see your point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`current` is a very bad way to differentiate.  If you have an application which carries out a call to `/current/users`, and then you upgrade your API so that `/current/users` returns different information, your application will break.

Stick with versioning.  A simple `/v1/users` is clear and concise, and when you add `/v2/users` then the applications using the old API endpoint will continue to work and you can update them as and if you require.

Comment: If it's for internal use only he can call it abracadabra... it's for internal use, and for ONE application - not application**s**

Comment: `/vX/blah` is exactly what Dropbox does, to mention a real world example.

Comment: You only shift versions when there is a major change in your API itself (exposing new resources, or new functionality). So if something hasn't changed from v1 to v2, you would migrate it directly. What you _don't want_ is to have some resources/functions in v1 and others in v2, this is the easiest way to problems with your API consumers (be they public or private).

Comment: @lee Don't copy paste. Try to identify the differences between v1 and v2 and reuse as much code as possible.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I don't quite understand this part "What you don't want is to have some resources/functions in v1 and others in v2, this is the easiest way to problems with your API consumers (be they public or private)".

Comment: @Tichodroma and by re-use do you mean inheritance? Does this not get messy. Most code sits in v1, v2 has a few breaking changes, v3 has a few more breaking changes and before you know it you have something like a git log. Everynow and then do you 'prune', e.g. no clients are using v1 anymore, so you integrate the code with the v2 'deltas' so that v2 is now your 'base'

Comment: @jgm - What are the usecases in which versioning is needed for internal api's? As I understand the API provider has a control over its clients so as the API's change the clients could also be updated. Am I missing any scenarios where versioning could be important for internal api's?

Comment: @AndyDufresne exactly the same use case as for external APIs: by using versioning you don't *need* to update all of the clients at the same time as the server.